# When does the queryset use its _result_cache, not hitting the database?

Tags: django, orm, django-queryset

I am confused with the time queryset uses its `_result_cache` or it directly hits the database.

For example (in python shell):

```
user = User.objects.all()  # User is one of my models   
print(user)  # show data in database (hitting the database)   
print(user._result_cache)  # output is None   
len(user)  # output is a nonzero number  
print(user._result_cache)  # this time, output is not None
```

So, my questions are:

1. Why the `_result_cache` is `None` after hitting the database?
2. Does the queryset is evaluated mean that the `_result_cache` is not `None`?
3. When does the queryset use its `_result_cache`, not hitting the database?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A queryset will cache its data in `self._result_cache` whenever the *complete* queryset is evaluated. This includes iterating over the queryset, calling `bool()`, `len()` or `list()`, or pickling the queryset.

The `print()` function indirectly calls `repr()` on the queryset. `repr()` will evaluate the queryset to include the data in the string representation, but it will not evaluate the *complete* queryset. Instead, it will [get a slice](https://github.com/django/django/blob/74742aa956d9cef0493b57f50f1cb7dc0f987fc6/django/db/models/query.py#L228) of the queryset and use that in the representation. This prevents huge queries when all you want is a simple string representation. Since only a slice is evaluated, it will not cache the results.

When the cache is filled, every method that does not create a new queryset object will use the cache instead of making a new query. In your specific example, if you switch the `print()` and `len()` statement, your queryset will only hit the database once:

```
user = User.objects.all()
len(user)  # complete queryset is evaluated
print(user._result_cache)  # cache is filled
print(user)  # slicing an evaluated queryset will not hit the database
print(user._result_cache)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !!!! I am puzzled by this `print()` function for a long time .

Comment: sorry , I have a question . In "repr() will evaluate the queryset to include the data in the string representation" , what does 'the string representation' mean ? and what is it ? (is `_result_cache` ?)

Comment: The string representation of an object is what you see printed to the console whenever you run `print(obj)`. In case of a queryset that's `<QuerySet [...]>`, where `...` contains actual data from the individual model instances.

Answer (score 3):

There is an explanation for this behavior :

When you use User.objects.all(),Database is not hit.When you do not iterate through the query set, the _result_cache is always None.But when you invoke len() function.The iteration will be done through query set, the database will be hit and resulting output will also set the result_cahce for that query set.
Here is the source code for len() function of Django :

```
def __len__(self):
    # Since __len__ is called quite frequently (for example, as part of
    # list(qs), we make some effort here to be as efficient as possible
    # whilst not messing up any existing iterators against the QuerySet.
    if self._result_cache is None:
        if self._iter:
            self._result_cache = list(self._iter)
        else:
            self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
    elif self._iter:
        self._result_cache.extend(self._iter)
    return len(self._result_cache)
```

Hope this clarifies all your questions. Thanks.

Comment: Queryset are lazy, and just `User.objects.all()` will definitely _not_ hit the database. Only evaluating the queryset, for instance when calling `print()` or `len()`, will hit the database.

Comment: @knbk What..?? User.objects.all() will not hit the database..??

Comment: That's right. Read up on [when querysets are evaluated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated). Specifically: _"Internally, a QuerySet can be constructed, filtered, sliced, and generally passed around without actually hitting the database. No database activity actually occurs until you do something to evaluate the queryset."_